# Why do python lists still use the __iadd__ method for += and not __iconcat__?

Tags: python

I see that the __iconcat__ method was added in 2.5, so is the continued use of __iadd__ just an historical legacy? Is there some reason it can't or hasn't been replaced by __iconcat__? Am I completely misunderstanding the purpose of __iconcat__?

Some possible reasons that occur to me are:

1. This change would break any code that overloads the list += operator
   via the __iadd__ method (although I highly doubt this is common practice, and anyway I don't see why py3k couldn't have broken compatibility).
2. __iadd__ and __iconcat__ are functionally equivalent,
   so the difference is purely semantic. Since these methods aren't
   called directly, having a slightly more meaningful method name isn't a good enough reason to make such a change.

I'm curious if anyone has any insight or historical perspective on this.

Answer (score 4):

`__concat__` and `__iconcat__` are parts of the `operator` module. They're not *special methods* for objects... See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames

Comment: But to quote the operator module docs:

"The operator module exports a set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python[...] The function names are those used for special class methods"
and:

"`a = iconcat(a, b)` is equivalent to `a += b` for _a_ and _b_ sequences."

So, wouldn't iconcat correspond to the += operator for lists?

Comment: @ebenpack it says *equivalent to*... but `+=` maps to the `__iadd__` special method...

Comment: @ebenpack you have to import the `operator` module to use `iconcat`. It's not the built-in implementation of `+=` for lists in python. The built-in implementation uses the special method `__iadd__` which is a part of the built-in list class. If `x` is a list, then `x.__iadd__(y)` is not the same as `operator.iadd(x, y)`.

Comment: I think you're both misunderstanding my question. I understand that `iconcat` is not a special method of list, and is not used for `+=`. I'm asking, purely out of curiosity, _why_ was it not used? Given that there are two operator methods corresponding to `+=` (`iconcat` and `iadd`), it seems as if the one that "is equivalent to `a += b` for a and b sequences" would be the obvious choice of method, just in terms of semantics. Since it is not (and since `iconcat` was only added in 2.5), I suspect that the reason is basically inertia. That's the sort of answer I'm after.

Comment: I think I'm causing some of this confusion myself. I'm only asking about the name of the special list method, not the method itself. Why is it still named `__iadd__`? Why wasn't the name of this method changed to `__iconcat__`? Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: @ebenpack `+=` should translate to one method. If it's `iadd` then it's generic - it's "adding" something together via `+=`... In the case of sequences and strings, the term *concatenate* makes sense. In the terms of numbers it doesn't. It started off short for *inplace add* so it's remained - it'd be horrible having multiple methods for the same operator - would one take priority over the other, or would you only be allowed to define one? And then, knowing which one to override in a class would be pot luck etc...

Comment: @jon-clements That makes sense. The inclusion of `iconcat` in `operator` is still a bit puzzling to me. My impression is that the `operator` function names are those that have been tacitly 'authorized' for special methods, yet the name `iconcat` isn't used anywhere. And `operator.iadd` functions perfectly well for concatenation. So why is it there at all?